# Prove the nonexistence of $p$-torsion for $p > 3$ in $E:y^2 = x^3 + ax$ for prime $a \geq 2$.

Tags: elliptic-curves

$$\Large\textbf{Problem}$$
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined by $y^2 = x^3 + ax$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is fourth-power free.  Then
\begin{aligned}
E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}} = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 & \text{if $-a$ is a square}\\
\mathbb{Z}_4 & \text{if $a = 4$}\\
\mathbb{Z}_2 & \text{if $a \neq 4$ and $-a$ is not a square}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}

Assume that $a \geq 2$ is a prime.  Prove that $E$ as above does not have $p$-torsion for any prime $p > 3$ i.e. that for any $p > 3$, $E(\mathbb{Q})$ does have any points of order $p$.

$$\Large\textbf{Attempts and Ideas}$$
We need to show that $E$ does not have $p$-torsion for any prime $p > 3$.  Since $a \geq 2$ is prime, $(0,0)$ is the point of order $2$ in $E(\mathbb{Q})$ and in $E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}}$.  By the discriminant of the elliptic curve formula, $\mathrm{Discr}_E = -4a^3$.  Since $a$ is prime, by Nagell-Lutz theorem, if $(\alpha, \beta) \in E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}}$ and $\beta^2 \mid -4a^3$, then $\beta \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm a\}$.  Either $a = 2$ or $a = 3$ or $a$ is any other odd prime.

If $a = 2$, then there are no rational points of the form $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\beta \in \{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4\}$.  So $E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}}$ contains $\infty$ and $(0,0)$, the point of order $2$.

If $a = 3$, then $\beta \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3\}$.  The torsion points are $(1,2)$ and $(1,-2)$.  But since $a = 3 \neq 4$ and $-a$ is not a square, $E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}} = \mathbb{Z}_2$.  So $(1,2)$ and $(1,-2)$ are points of order $4$.

If $a$ is any other odd prime, then by hypothesis there are no other torsion points in $E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}}$.  So this group contains $\infty$ and $(0,0)$.

I am stuck for this part since I am not quite sure about my approach.  Any comments or thoughts?

Comment: This is killing me, as I have a very tough doubt here: if the torsion subgroup of the curve is what you wrote in your question, isn't it terribly obvious this group has no $\;p$-torsion elements for a prime $\;p>3\;$ ??

Comment: Yes, that is true, but my professor expects me the full proof of this.  I had the same thoughts, but I decided to write 'em out to see what I get.

Comment: I could have included 'em here, so you will understand what is going on with the question I have.  Otherwise, people like you will go a bit too crazy about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Proposition 6.1 in Chapter X of "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by J. H. Silverman, so you can look it up there.

Comment: Good.  Finally, someone tells me where to find the result.

Answer (score 0):

If $E(\mathbb Q)^{tor}$ is as you described (where did you find that result?), so the order of the torsion-points is 2 or 4. The order of a torsion point can't be $p>3$, with p prime. No ?

Comment: It's the theorem.  This is how $E(\mathbb{Q})^{\text{tor}}$ is defined based on my professor's notes